# Как вывести массив примитивных типов/массив структур в двоичный файл?

Tags: массивы, файлы, hex, c++

Имеем:

```
unsigned int* Testing = new unsigned int[4];
Testing[0]=66666666;
Testing[1]=66666666;
Testing[2]=66666666;
Testing[3]=66666666;
```

Хотим запихнуть это в бинарный файл. Для этого пишем такой код:

```
std::ofstream outfile(Name,ios::app|ios::binary|ios::out);
for (int i=0;i<sizeof(Testing)/sizeof(Testing[0]);i++)
    outfile.write((char*)&Testing[i],sizeof(Testing[i]));
outfile.close();
```

В файле вместо:

```
03F940AA 03F940AA 03F940AA 03F940AA
```

Оказывается:

```
AA40F903 AA40F903 AA40F903 AA40F903
```

Скорее всего проблема в cast конверсии или я что-то упустил? Каким еще способом можно вывести массив примитивных типов в бинарный файл? Что делать в случае массива структур состоящих из примитивных типов? Если я сделаю обратную конверсию из массива char[4] AA40F903 в unsigned int во время чтения таким образом:

```
 unsigned int x;
 outfile.read((char*)&x, sizeof(unsigned int));
```

там в x окажется 66666666 или 2856384771?

Comment: - У вас кстати, ошибка - `sizeof(Testing) / sizeof(Testing[0])` неприменимо для указателей.

- На `Solaris` ваш код вывел бы `03F940AA` в силу того, что ОС `big-endian`.

- Там окажется `66666666,` если вы не будете, например, записывать данные на `little-endian` системе, а читать на `big-endian`.

Comment: Да я понял здесь little-endian порядок байт. Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@igumnov](/users/7053/igumnov), все у Вас правильно.

Просто младшие (наименее значимые) разряды в целых числах размещаются в байтах с **меньшим** адресом и поэтому в файле оказываются **слева**.

Просто посмотрите на свои данные внимательно.

Массивы структур пишете в принципе также.

```
struct { int f1; double f2; long long f3; char f4[10] } x[5] = { .... };
write(fd,x,sizeof(x)); // за один раз
```

Читать

```
read(fd,&x[3],sizeof(x[0])*2); // читаем последние два элемента
```

Comment: - Если отправить такую штуку по сети с `Windows` на `Mac OS X / PowerPC`, то можно приятно удивиться.

- Для этого кейса, как мне известно, придуманы вещи типа http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/binary/binary_little.html

Comment: @Котик, действительно для сети (и вообще обмена между приложениями даже через ленту, флэшку и т.п.) лучше так не делать. 

Если писать в локальные файлы, то в самый раз.

Answer (score 2):

Заметили, что байты четверками наоборот? это потому что есть такое понятие как [порядок байт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Вам нужно либо int разворачивать, либо  писать по одному байту, разделяя int - char'ом в том порядке, который Вы пожелаете.